# How to initialize Google Analytics safely when an external JS library is also attempting to do so?

Tags: google-analytics

We are using google tag manager to deploy google analytics.  This works great pretty much everywhere, except on places that run JS from a specific vendor.

This vendor does its own bootstrapping of google analytics, creates its own tracker, and then tracks interactions (presumably) on the widget it is creating.

The problem is that there is a race condition, it seems which ever script initializes first "wins".

According to this:  https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=472

There is no support for GA being initted into different namespaces; but all the references to creating multiple trackers make the basic assumption that there is one controlling party.

How can I safely bootstrap GA when there may or may not be another JS library attempting the same thing?

Comment: Does the widget code use the `ga` name, or do they use a custom name?

Comment: They use a custom name.

Comment: They shouldn't be doing that. If you have a relationship with them, I'd reach out and tell them not to. Third party code should never interfere with a host site's Google Analytics implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

analytics.js supports renaming the global `ga()` command queue via `window.GoogleAnalyticsObject`. In other words, when analytics.js downloads, it looks to see if a value is set on `window.GoogleAnalyticsObject`, and if it finds one, it assumes that name is the name of the global command queue function. If it doesn't find one, it assume the default name `ga`.

Third-party plugins, widgets, or any other code that you load on your page should respect the value you (the host) have assigned to `window.GoogleAnalyticsObject`. They should **not** be modifying it themselves.

If you're a third-party plugin author, you should be checking to see if the host page has renamed the command queue function.

Here's an example that gets a reference to whatever value the host page has set for the `ga()` command queue:

```
var gaReference = window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject || 'ga'];
```

Once you have the reference you can use it as you normally would; however, you should never use the [default tracker name](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#naming_trackers) since that's most likely what the host page is using:

```
gaReference('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {name: 'someUniquePluginName'});
gaReference('someUniquePluginName.send', 'pageview');
```